# Left Swipe - нужен пример перехода к Activity

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. 
 Нужен простой пример перехода к Activity по свайпу влево. Хочу реализовать возврат назад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать `ViewPager`. В таком случае перелистывание будет выполняться не к предыдущей `Activity`, а к предыдущему фрагменту.

[Хороший пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html).